# Numbers above the notes on a music sheet

Tags: theory, violin

I am wondering what the numbers above the notes (1 up to 16) on the second line seen in the picture mean ? In other words, how should one play these notes? It is an excerpt from Sympthony No 9 from Schubert.
Thanks.
[image: Numbers 1–16 and 1–7 above identical tremolos]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The numbers are just to help keep track of how many times the repeated note has been played. With that many measures playing exactly the same thing, it's easy to lose track.

They don't affect the execution of the music.